# How to use UIView's UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn in iOS?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to add subview with UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn into MyMainView.
I have two UIView in my ViewController.xib file.
There is a one button in MainView , when I clicked that button, I want to call another view with UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn.

In some of iOS app, the new view appear from the below with slide.
I think that's used with UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn.
I also want to do like that.
If I'm wrong,please guide me how to do that.
Or where can I read that function?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
AViewController *aVC = [[AViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AViewController" bundle:nil];
//[self.navigationController pushViewController:aVC animated:NO];
[UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:aVC.view duration:0.5f options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn completion:^(BOOL doneDissolve){
            [self.view addSubview:aVC.view];
        }];
 [aVC release];
```